# Quantum field theory alternatives

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Quantum field theory arises from the requirement that the S-matrix is lorentz scalar and obeys the cluster decomposition principle.

I want to know if there are *other ways to build invariant S-Matrices* that obey the cluster decomposition principle without using quantum field theory. QFT is the most natural way to do it but I'm interested in other possible approaches.

Comment: It would seem like string theory should also have a consistent S-matrix, though it is not a theory of particles (hence not exactly a QFT)

Comment: Try browsing the string theory questions on physics.SE. The S-matrix for strings has been talked about quite a bit though I can't pull up the relevant questions right away.